# Django: test successful loading of static files

Tags: python, django, automated-tests, django-testing

Is it possible to test successful loading of static page components in Django automatic test?

For example, using django test client, besides testing the `client.get('x').status_code` to be 200, I want to test if all page's static resources (linked css and js files) are successfully loaded.

If its not possible using `client`, Is there a plugin or suplementary test system, e.g. Selenium, to enable such type of tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you want to find out if django's staticfile finder is able to find your static resources.

Consider your app name is `my_app`. You have a folder called `static` inside it. You again have a folder called `my_app` inside it which contains your static resource, let's say some image named 'test.jpg'.

```
myapp
|-- __init__.py 
`-- models.py
`-- static
    `-- myapp
        `-- test.jpg

from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

class TestStaticFiles(TestCase):
"""Check if app contains required static files"""
def test_images(self):
    abs_path = finders.find('myapp/test.jpg')
    self.assertTrue(staticfiles_storage.exists(abs_path))
```

`finders` looks inside `static/` subdirectory of all apps to find the static resource.

Answer (score 1):

I just found myself with a very similar issue, although I wanted to verify if the file was included in the page rather than check it was loaded, because I include it selectively.

To do so, I simply checked using assertContains:

```python
def test_static_file_included(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('my-view'))
    self.assertContains(response, 'staticfilename.js')
```

Keep in mind that `staticfilename.js` could be included somewhere else in the page.

`assertContains` will check if the response status_code is ok, then check if the search str is included in `response.content`.

Comment: This won't check if the link is broken though, because `staticfilename.js` will still be in the response.